# Como puedo estructurar mi json?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una tabla llamada car, la cual tiene los campos, brand, model y type.

Requiero hacer lo siguiente:
{
brand{
model : cantidad
}
}

Es decir, por cada marca de carro, desglosar los modelos y poner la cantidad.

He intentado con Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> pero hasta ahora no logro conseguirlo, pues al hacer la consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar, hay la posibilidad de que tanto la marca o el modelo se repitan, por lo cual al hacer uso del Dictionary, me marca error señalando que la clave volvo ya se ha añadido. en teoría lo de la imagen debería devolverlo de la siguiente manera:

Fiat{
"Model" T : 1
},
Lamborghini{
"Grand Cherokee" : 1
},
Volvo{
"Expedition" : 1,
"PT Cruiser" : 1
}

Y así consecutivamente, si tuviera dos PT Cruiser de la marca Volvo debería ser
Volvo{
"Expedition" : 1,
"PT Cruiser" : 2
}

Espero haberme explicado, agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un diccionario cuyo valor sea una lista de diccionarios:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>>>
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo para rellenar el objeto con la información que dices y cómo la obtendrías en formato JSON:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>>>
{
    ["Fiat"] = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>{new Dictionary<string, int>{["Model T"] = 1}},
    ["Lamborghini"] = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>{new Dictionary<string, int>{["Grand Cherokee"] = 1}},
    ["Volvo"] = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>{new Dictionary<string, int>{["Expedition"] = 1}, new Dictionary<string, int>{["PT Cruiser"] = 1}}
};
```

Resultado: `{"Fiat":[{"Model T":1}],"Lamborghini":[{"Grand Cherokee":1}],"Volvo":[{"Expedition":1},{"PT Cruiser":1}]}`

Comment: Es justo lo que yo necesitaba, gracias!!